# How to force propertyChange event

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have a large 2 dimensional array where I update values in place and my other polymer elements do not get notified of changes.  I have an idea why, and I think my solution is to force a property change event, but I'm not sure.

For a model element item like this...

```
<polymer-element name="my-model" attributes="rows">
...
<script>
  ...
  this.rows[0][0] = newValue;
</script>
```

I find when I use it in a view element like this...

```
<my-view rows="{{model.rows}}"></my-view>
```

where the view's implementation is like this...

```
<polymer-element name="my-view" attributes="rows">
<template>
   <template repeat="{{row in rows}}">
     <template repeat="{{col, i in cols}}">
       {{row[i]}}
     </template>
   </template>
</template>
```

my view does not get updated unless I reset the array value in the model

```
this.rows = []
```

Can I somehow force a property change event.  I tried...

```
this.rows = this.rows
```

..and...

```
this.notifyPropertyChanged('rows', this.rows, this.rows)
```

and no luck.  Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a mistake in your second template. Since you're using named scoped, your second template needs to be `{{col, i in row}}`:

```
<template repeat="{{row in rows}}">
  <template repeat="{{col, i in row}}">
```

This worked for me: http://jsbin.com/sidagomu/1/edit

(click the element -> data updates -> template re-renders)

Comment: That worked. Thanks. NOTE: I was iterating over "cols" which would have the same length as "row" so programatically it shouldn't matter when i ultimately just call "row[i]".  But because I didn't use "row", polymer didn't create an automatic observable binding.  I hope to not make this mistake again now that i see the issue.

Comment: I think this may be a bug. If you have:

    `this.cols = [ "One", "Two", "Three" ];`

Then `cols` is in scope in the inner template and `{{col, i in cols}}` should work. I can't see why `row[i]` updates in one case and not in the other.

In fact, even if you use `{{col, i in [ 1, 2, 3 ]}}`, the binding doesn't update. Something's fishy.

That said, using `{{col in row}}` and `{{col}}` is straightforward and should work reliably.